# Difficulty with Adding a Reference in Visual Studio (Windows Azure StorageClient)

Tags: visual-studio, azure, project-reference

I've been following alone with this [tutorial](http://www.robbagby.com/azure/azure-application-part-2-access-azure-table-storage). Everything is going great, until I get to this part:

> Set a reference to the StorageClient
>   library.  You can either add the
>   sample project to the solution and add
>   a project reference or you can add a
>   reference to the compiled dll.  I am
>   going to add the StorageClient project
>   to the solution and add a project
>   reference.

I am not able to find the StorageClient project. I have SDK v1.2, and it has samples-cs.zip. StorageClient is not there.

The SDK does have `ref/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll`. I tried adding a reference to it in my ASP project, but it's not working. VS does not recognize the type `TableStorageEntity`, nor the namespace `Microsoft.Samples.ServiceHosting.StorageClient`.

What am I doing wrong? Can I just find the `StorageClient` somewhere and use that? If it was taken out of the SDK, does it mean that it's not supported any more? If so, why have the DLL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the tutorial you're looking at is from mid-2009, when the storage client library was an add-on that was distributed as a sample with the SDK.

With the latest SDK (which I see you're using), the Azure storage support is now officially part of the SDK. The reference you're looking for is Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.

Take a look at the [Azure platform training kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en---) - they should have updated samples.

Also: when you create a new cloud project with v1.2, you'll see that you automatically get references to the Azure dll's and don't need to manually add them. This includes:

- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient